Contract verify

I get such error of compilation in Optimism Sepolia testnet network.The contract succesfully compiles using hardhat with needed configuration.What should I do to get verified the contract ?

Probably your contract is greater than the maximum size, which is around 24 kb — 25 kb.
You can run
forge build --sizes

To verify the sizes
If that's the case, head over to this article.
Or try to run it with the flag --via-ir. It will downscale a little bit your contract size

can you please send the code snippet ,
I also faced the same issue; in my case, i had used more than 10 parameters when this error occured. AfterI removed/optimised it , it worked for me.
Can you please check this? Thanks!

yeah i also think chnaging function(e.g get as an argument a struct) will be solution.But the problem is that i dont want to modify the code
